# Processo não executa de forma elevada

Tags: c#, windows

Fiz um programa para executar o processo de ativação do windows de forma elevada mas recebo a mensagem de privilegio insuficiente apesar de estar com verb = Runas

```
 var senhaSegura = new System.Security.SecureString();
 var senha = "****"
 foreach (char c in senha)
    senhaSegura.AppendChar(c);
 var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo{
    FileName = "cscript.exe",
    WorkingDirectory = @"c:\windows\system32\",
    UserName = "admin",
    Domain = "transp",
    Password = senhaSegura, //Converte a senha em uma senha segura.
    Verb = "runas", //Aqui executa de forma elevada
    Arguments = "slmgr.vbs -ipk meu serial",
    UseShellExecute = false
    };
```

Comment: Como sua aplicação será executada? É uma console application que gera um .exe comum?

Comment: Está sendo executada no visual studio 2019

Comment: você tem certeza de que esse aplicativo deve trabalhar no `c:\windows\system32\`

Comment: Sim se vc buscar na pasta  c:\windows\system32\ o cscript vai estar lá.

Comment: Coloque o manifesto do seu aplicativo aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Se não me engano a única maneira de fazer isso no Windows é executar a sua aplicação desde o início com privilégios elevados. Não é possível elevar seus privilégios durante a execução.
Execute o .exe gerado usando o "Executar como administrador" do Windows ou execute o seu Visual Studio como administrador para testar.

P.S: Desculpem por postar uma interação como resposta. É que ainda não tenho reputação o bastante para comentar.

Comment: Eu vi aqui no site dizendo que funciona. dá uma olhada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767759/processstartinfo-verb-runas-not-working

Comment: Se você executar o comando `runas` via linha de comando verá na documentação que é obrigatório informar o usuário desejado como argumento. Por exemplo: `runas /user:nome_usuario "cmd.exe"`. Tente perguntar o usuário antes via `Console.ReadLine()` e passe como argumento.

Comment: O usuario se encontra na linha  UserName = "admin",

Comment: Eu imagino que dessa maneira o `runas` não vai conseguir funcionar. Porque ele é um simples utilitário CLI. Tente adicionar junto ao verb ou aos argumentos. Imagino que seu resultado seja mais positivo.

Comment: poderia dar o exemplo que está propondo?